How can I track/observe when captions are changed in a youtube video with javascript?
I am creating a Chrome extension and want to know when a user is changing the subtitles of a video they are viewing.
I know I can get the currently playing subtitle from the Youtube video player using player.getOptions("captions", "track"), but how can I come to know when the subtitle is changed?
I think it'll be possible to set up a mutation observer and observe when the Subtitles/CC innerText changes (i.e. on selecting a subtitle, it shows the language in the settings menu and we can grab the subtitle's name text from there), but there are some downsides and this does not seem to be the way it's done through extensions like Language Reactor.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Try addEventListener('yt-action', .... and see if it fires for the change.
